# Highlight column based on current date and time

Tags: excel, formatting, office365

Good day,

For work I have a sort of attendance sheet for the whole week, where each day has two timeslots.
To make it "quicker" to work with, I'd like to highlight relevant sections; in this case the columns corresponding to the current date and time.

Is there some formula for conditional formatting, or perhaps VBA code that could do this? For reference I added a screenshot of the sheet.

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve for example is that if I open the sheet on monday morning, april 1st at say 10 AM, the whole column F-I will be highlighted. If I open the sheet in the afternoon, column K-N will be highlighted, and so on.

Appearance of cells is not fixed in stone, so if I would need to make adjustments to optimize the solution, that's definitely a possibility.

At this point, the only somewhat proper solution is conditional formatting for "Today". But that only highlights the cells with the current date and does not account for the time.

I'd also like to highlight the entire column, not just the cells.

[image]

Comment: *if I open the sheet on monday morning, april 1st at say 10 AM, the whole column F-I will be highlighted. If I open the sheet in the afternoon, column K-N will be highlighted, and so on* Check [NOW function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/now-function-3337fd29-145a-4347-b2e6-20c904739c46) to handle date and time

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.